# How to change Mat-Datepicker date format to yyyy-MM-dd?

Tags: angular, mat-datepicker

I use mat-datepicker for choosing date. Also I set locale for date picker(it can be 'de' or 'en'). How can I set format to be always yyyy-MM-dd and not changing depending on locale?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the MAT_DATE_LOCALE.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'},
  ],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

Here is an example: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

**Edit:**
Try with dateAdapter:

```
 import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('de'); //dd/MM/yyyy

}
```

Comment: i have the option to change language so it can be german(de) or english(en). Default is 'de', so when it's 'de' the format is dd.MM.yyyy and when 'en' format is MM/dd/yyyy. I need to format always be dd-MM-yyyy and not depending on locale